# WSO2 encrypt/decrypt password (string) with public-private keys

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, wso2

In WSO2 ESB (4.8.1) in BAM profile, when I export it (BAM profile), I noticed that password is encrypted. I find out that if I will have private and public key I could encrypt/decrypt password, so I write this:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("wso2carbon.jks");

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(is, "wso2carbon".toCharArray());

        String alias = "wso2carbon";

        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, "wso2carbon".toCharArray());
        if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
            Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

            PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

            String dataToBeEncrypted = "admin";
            String adminToDecrypted = "kuv2MubUUveMyv6GeHrXr9il59ajJIqUI4eoYHcgGKf/BBFOWn96NTjJQI+wYbWjKW6r79S7L7ZzgYeWx7DlGbff5X3pBN2Gh9yV0BHP1E93QtFqR7uTWi141Tr7V7ZwScwNqJbiNoV+vyLbsqKJE7T3nP8Ih9Y6omygbcLcHzg=";

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            String encryptedData = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(dataToBeEncrypted.getBytes()));
            System.out.println("Encrypted Data: " + encryptedData);

            Cipher dipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

            dipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            System.out.println(new String(dipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData))));

        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, becasue 'admin' is encrypted and decrypted after. But when I copy this encrypted value and want paste it in my BAM profle password, ESB can't get it and password is blank and in console I get this:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,429]
Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x2) was found in the element content of the document.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:842)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:100)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.getElementText(SwitchingWrapper.java:962)
```

The second issue is, when I try to decrypt password (WSO2 ESB encrypt it by export BAM profile, and it is 'adminToDecrypted') I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

So, maybe I'm doing something wrong or I miss something important. Maybe there is other way to do this. Maybe there is a class in WSO2 repo where I can find out how it works?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that in my code I get new encrypted password every time when I run the code but in WSO2 ESB I get always the same string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When encrypting/encoding and decoding/decrypting, try the following:

```
org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.getDefaultCryptoUtil().encryptAndBase64Encode(value.getBytes())
```

To decode/decrypt, use the method:

```
base64DecodeAndDecrypt()
```

You'll have to add a dependency for org.wso2.carbon.core (or org.wso2.carbon.utils, try both of these) to get this working (check your `<product>/repository/components/plugins` to find the correct version of the dependency)

I'm not exactly sure whether this will work for your case, but this is how it's done in most of the carbon-based products.